# Нужно ли здесь обособление и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Предложение:

> Диего, вопреки стереотипу об аргентинцах как о смуглокожих, существенно походил на сомалийского негра.

Comment: Эту фразу вы сами придумали? Ужас какой. "Существенно походил" – этта што??

Comment: Походил – был похожим. Быть похожим можно в разной степени: чуть-чуть или очень сильно. А в данном случае эта степень ещё и важна для нас, для каких-то выводов. Если был похожим чуть-чуть – может быть для нашего дела (о подробностях которого вы по этому предложению знать не можете) это не имеет значение. А если сильно – то и на выводы влияет существенно, для нас существенно – ценный факт. Тем не менее про стереотип сочинил, что там у них я не знаю.

Comment: Походить существенно - некорректная сочетаемость, хотя можно существенно отличаться. Лучше сказать: весьма походил, например: "Мой давний приятель, славный иудей Валера Барахманский, работавший токарем на Опытном заводе Балтийского пароходства, весьма походил на индийца".

Comment: В этой многострадальной фразе еще и фактическая ошибка, и логическая. Смуглокожие аргентинцы - не может быть такого стереотипа. Они типичные белые. Это фактическая ошибка. Вопреки смуглокожести похож на негра?! - а это логическая.

Comment: Это не фактическая ошибка, а сказочка вырванная из контекста, ни каким фактом из реального мира она не должна подчинятся.

Comment: Насчёт логической не знаю, вряд ли... Есть стереотип (мнение очевидное и по большому счёту верное, если не вдаваться в подробности: регионы там и пр.) – он в пользу того, что Диего смуглокожий. Это конкретный фактор, информация влияющая на вывод и наше мнение. И тут мы в бинокль увидали Диего. В противовес (вопреки) ИНФОРМАЦИИ (стереотипу, может ошибочному в конкретной ситуации) уже противоположенная инфа – мы увидели, что Диего чёрный. Дальше карлик жёлудь со мной взвесит всё и придёт к выводу: доверится тому, что думает народец (это для смеха, не приплетайте определение) или глазам своим.

Comment: Почему ошибочная информация не может противоречить (быть вопреки) с железобетонными сведениями, полученными тем более впоследствии?

Comment: "Вопреки смуглокожести похож на негра" – ну это извратили.

Comment: А я узнала, какого цвета сомалийские негры.  Существует один типичный цвет кожи сомалийцев – богатый, блестящий, шоколадно-бурый, которым обладает семь восьмых сомалийцев. Очень немногие темнее, есть и светло-бурые индивиды, а в очень редких случаях встречаются сомалийцы, светлые, как арабы. Сомалийцы наименее негроидный народ во всей Восточной Африке. http://iknigi.net/avtor-karlton-kun/76750-rasy-evropy-karlton-kun/read/page-42.html

Comment: Чёрные, красные, каловые – не суть важно для того, чтоб назвать такого негром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**ВОПРЕКИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_92) (чему), предлог
Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «вопреки», обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).

Обособляются обороты, которые располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым:
*К чистописанию по косым линейкам **она**, вопреки общему обыкновению учащихся, **чувствовала** большую склонность...* (А. Куприн. Яма)

В Вашем предложении подлежащее ***Диего*** и сказуемое ***походил*** разделены оборотом, поэтому он (оборот) и обособляется.

***Диего***, вопреки стереотипу об аргентинцах как о смуглокожих, существенно **походил** на сомалийского негра.

[Пунктуация с предлогом "вопреки"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)